# How to direct host's browser to guest VM?

Tags: centos, networking, vmware

Host - *Windows 7*

Guest - *CentOS 7*

I have set up a CentOS VM using VMware Player. I can now connect to the internet (ping google.com, install packages using yum are all successful) after changing the network settings to use DHCP as directed in the reponse to my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215337/how-to-connect-centos-virtual-machine-on-vmware-to-the-internet/215465?noredirect=1#comment365554_215465).

I'm now trying to complete the last part of Step One of this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-6). But after running `ifconfig eno16777736 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'` to verify that my VM's IP address is `192.168.22.128` - directing my browser to that address fails to load anything (connection timeout). (I've checked that the `httpd` service is running.)

I can ping `192.168.22.128` successfully from the command line of the host though.

The network settings for the VM are using NAT. I tried switching to a bridged connection thinking that would work better - but then the VM didn't even appear to have an IP address and couldn't connect to the internet at all - failed to ping 8.8.4.4 (I don't understand exactly what was being changed by doing that).

Can anyone explain how to get the browser to connect to the VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When ping works you probably have a firewall rule on the VM which blocks Port 80.

`firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` to get the zone argument.

`firewall-cmd --zone=ZONE --add-service=http --permanent` to open the port.

`firewall-cmd --reload` to activate the rule.

You could substitute `--add-service=http` with `--add-port=80/tcp`.

Comment: Running the first command gives `public    interfaces: eno16777736`
Running the second command (with sudo) gives `INVALID_ZONE: ZONE`. What should ZONE be substituted with?

Comment: the zone is "public" then.

Comment: You just saved my life